# RegEx Validation for Specific Easily Guessed Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation

So I am completely not knowing in where to start in creating a RegEx validation pattern in my React application.

I have various input boxes, of which (*depending on certain criteria*) there will be either a 3, 4, 5, or 6 digit passcode (*and that same number of input boxes rendered on screen to accept 1 number each*).

After s `Save` or `Continue` button is clicked, the individual inputs are stored in an array, and then `join`ed to be one number. It is this final number that I must validate.

What I need to do is write a validation method - *in React* - which performs the following validations:

**For 3 digits:**

> Cannot be 999, 998, or include 11 immediately after the first digit (*911, 611, etc.*)

**For 4 digits:**

> Cannot be 9999, 9998, or include 11 immediately after the first digit (*8112, 5112, etc.*)

**For 5 digits:**

> Cannot be 99999, 99998, or include 11 immediately after the first digit (*71122, 41122, etc.*)

**For 6 digits:**

> Cannot be 999999, 999998, or include 11 immediately after the first digit (*611222, 311222, etc.*)

It pains me to do so, but I am really lacking in the RegEx space, and am uncertain how to go about implementing something like this.

It should also be noted that I am not using *Redux* or the validations that come along with it. Gotta attack this one with a util method that accepts an argument (*the final number retrieved from the input boxes*) and runs the validation against that (*displaying an error message if there is a failure*)

Is there anyone that can provide some insight on how to go about getting started for the RegEx...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `^(?!9+[98]$|\d1{2})\d{3,6}$`

Comment: Holy crap! That was fast! You should write that as an answer so that I can accept it, because it seems that this does what I need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment below your question, you can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6iBVk4/1)

```
^(?!9+[98]$|\d1{2})\d{3,6}$
```

How it works:

- `^` assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!9+[98]$|\d1{2})` negative lookahead ensuring either of the the following options does not proceed

  - `9+[98]$` matches `9` one or more times, then either `9` or `8`, then the end of the line
  - `\d1{2})` matches any digit, followed by `1` twice
- `\d{3,6}` matches between 3 and 6 digits
- `$` assert position at the end of the line

Since the negative lookahead follows the start of line anchor, we also ensure the lookahead starts at that position, that's why `\d1{2}` matches `011`, `111`, `211`, ..., `911` and not `1211` or others.

Code below:

```js
s = ['999','998','911','611','9999','9998','8112','5112','99999','99998','71122','41122','999999','999998','611222','311222','123','6211','99989','121212']
r = /^(?!9+[98]$|\d1{2})\d{3,6}$/
for (x of s) {
  console.log(x.match(r) ? x + ': true' : x + ': false')
}
```

--

### Edit

The OP mentioned that `999` and `998` placed anywhere in the string should invalidate it:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6iBVk4/3)

```
^(?!\d*9{2}[98]|\d1{2})\d{3,6}$
```

Same regex as above except for the first option in the negative lookahead. It's now `\d*9{2}[98]`, matching `999` or `998` anywhere in the string (preceded by any number of digits).

```js
s = ['999','998','911','611','9999','9998','8112','5112','99999','99998','71122','41122','999999','999998','611222','311222','123','6211','99989','121212']
r = /^(?!\d*9{2}[98]|\d1{2})\d{3,6}$/
for (x of s) {
  console.log(x.match(r) ? x + ': true' : x + ': false')
}
```

--

### Edit #2

The OP mentioned that the format of `0N11` should be invalidated (not just `N11`):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6iBVk4/4)

```
^(?!\d*9{2}[98]|[01]?\d1{2})\d{3,6}$
```

Same regex as above except for the second option in the negative lookahead. It's now `[01]?\d1{2}`, matching `0` or `1` optionally, followed by any digit, then `11` (so `011`, `111`, `211`, ..., `911`, `0011`, `0111`, `0211`, `0311`, ..., `0911`, `1011`, `1111`, `1211`, ..., `1911`).

```js
s = ['999','998','911','611','9999','9998','8112','5112','99999','99998','71122','41122','999999','999998','611222','311222','123','6211','99989','121212']
r = /^(?!\d*9{2}[98]|[01]?\d1{2})\d{3,6}$/
for (x of s) {
  console.log(x.match(r) ? x + ': true' : x + ': false')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining all of that! I see in your code snippet - after running it - that the number 99989 comes back as ```true```, but that is something that is not allowed, so it should come back as a failure (```false```)

Comment: Any combination of numbers that are not allowed should make the entire validation fail. So even if a 6 digit number starts with 999, that should cause the failure immediately. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Lushmoney can you more clearly define the rules? According to your examples it's only numbers that are 9 one or more times, then 9 or 8. I'll change my answer accordingly thereafter.

Comment: For example, if a user is to enter a 6 digit extension, if anywhere in that 6 digit number, the pattern of ```999``` (_or any other pattern that is not allowed_) is found, the validation should then fail. Here you have ```999``` failing (_which is correct_), but then ```99989``` passes, which it should not, because the pattern of ```999``` is found in ```99989```, so it should automatically fail because of that. Hope that clears it up...

Comment: @Lushmoney does the same apply for `11` or is that only if `11` is second/third character?

Comment: For the ```11``` validation, it should fail when any number entered has the pattern of ```N11``` or ```0N11``` or ```1N11```, (_where ```N``` is any number from 0 to 9_).

Comment: @Lushmoney to clarify on your last point, `1211`, `11211` and `1121` should pass or fail? In your question you mention *after the first digit* - P.S. I updated my answer to your previous comment's specs.

Comment: ```1211``` should not pass, ```11211``` can pass, and ```1121``` can pass, but something like ```3211``` is ok

Comment: @Lushmoney what would cause `1211` to fail, but `11211` and `3211` to pass? Can you elaborate on the rule?

Comment: ```0N11``` and ```1N11``` is just a specific pattern used elsewhere in the app, so that series of numbers is not allowed, just in that particular format. Another failure would be if ```11``` comes immediately after the first digit - ```411``` would fail, ```5112``` would fail

Comment: So would `[01]?\d11` work for that case (optionally `0` or `1`, then any digit, then `11`)?

Comment: thank you SOOOO much for this!! I really appreciate you taking the time to tweak and perfect this. You saved me! Thanks a billion!!